# After Chrome update to latest version(108.0.5359.95) , Javascript window.print() not working properly. Table jump to new page

Tags: javascript, c#, report

Recently Chrome updated to latest version 108.0.5359.95 which impact on JavaScript window.print() function. In print review or after print found my table jumping on new pages.

I tried with  css

```
   .report {
        margin-bottom: 0px !important;
        page-break-before: avoid;
        page-break-inside: avoid;
    }
```

There will be no page break before table at printing report.

Answer (score 0):

Might be related to this [post](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/191619088/print-preview-broken-in-last-update?hl=en), which mentions this [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1399313).